# How do you return a 'success' message to the frontend using onFinalize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am currently using a ReactJs frontend with the Firebase Javascript SDK. It is hooked up to a firebase-functions storage emulator using NodeJS in the backend.

Usually, I am able to call a `functions.https.onCall(...)` cloud function (that has been set up with nodejs) from my frontend and receive a promise, and then I can use the data in the front end normally.

However, using `functions.storage.object().onFinalize(...)` in the backend, I am trying to force some sort of way to return a success message to my front end after a file has successfully been processed.

Here is what I've tried:

My backend code (Nodejs):

```
exports.processMedia = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) =>{
// Here I successfully process any uploaded images

// Issue - After the media has been processed, I'd like to return a message that can be used to update the UI. I've tried to return a new promise like so:

return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        return resolve("Success");
    });
})
```

And then in my React UI, I am trying to capture the return message from the backend using a `httpsCallable('processMedia')` function because I don't know how else to try to get the response.

```
async processMedia(){
    const processMediaCallable = this.functions.httpsCallable('processMedia');
    return processMediaCallable;
}
```

Then I try to log out the values from the promise:

```
async function getProcessedMessage(){
    await firebase.processMedia().then((val) => {
        console.log(val);
    }); 
}
```

I get this output in the browser console for `val` after I've uploaded a file in the UI and `processMedia()` in the backend has completed:

```
ƒ (data) {
      return _this.call(name, data, options || {});
    }
```

I am trying to output a success message here. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, if my answer was helpful you can accept/upvote it else feel free to ask further queries. [What should I do when someone answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return a response to client from a background function. When a user uploads any file to your Firebase storage they get a success response and the function triggered from that event has nothing to do with client. There's a workaround for using [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) which you can use to emit the response to user.

To break it down in simple steps:

1. Upload file to Firebase Storage
2. Create a realtime database listener on client side
3. After all processing in your Cloud Function, write something in the database and that'll be delivered to your user.

**Client:**

```
async function uploadFile() { 
  // upload to firebase storage
  const alertRef = firebase.database().ref(`alerts/${userID}`);
  alertRef.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    // Alert received from cloud function
    // Delete this alert from database
    snapshot.ref.set(null)
  });
}
```

**Cloud function:**

```
exports.processMedia = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => { 
  // Process the file
  // Add alert in realtime database
  const alertRef = firebase.database().ref(`alerts/${userID}`).push()
  return alertRef.set({...}) // add any data you would like to pass to client side
})
```

> `child_added` event is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path. The listener is passed a snapshot containing the new child's data.

That being said just make sure you are not alerting users multiple times with same notification.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. It makes sense. I think I can achieve the same thing using cloud firestore too, right? Or is the `child_added` parameter specific to realtime databases? My project uses cloud firestore heavily and I'd like to avoid setting up a realtime db if possible.

Comment: @uponly Yes you can. Firestore has realtine listeners too